# Richfaces: Validation of inputTexts in a rich:datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I use a `rich:dataTable` where the user can add new rows. One of this rows contains two `<h:inputText>` for arrival and departure time. These fields should be validated immediately when the user move on (leave/blur the input text). The validation works quite good, wrong inputs are detected. Here is the `rich:column`.

```html
<rich:column>
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{txt.detail_itinerary_times}" />
</f:facet>
<h:inputText id="arrivalTime" value="#{stop.arrival}" 
    validatorMessage="{txt.error_detailview_notatime}" size="5">
    <f:validateRegex 
        pattern="^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))$" />
    <rich:validator />  
</h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="departureTime" value="#{stop.departure}" 
    validatorMessage="#{txt.error_detailview_notatime}" size="5">
    <f:validateRegex 
        pattern="^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))$" />
    <rich:validator />
</h:inputText>
<rich:message for="arrivalTime departureTime" />
```

Here comes the problem: If there are 20 rows in this datatable and you enter one wrong time, the *validation failed* message is displayed twenty times, for every row, for every input field. But it should only displayed at the input field, where the wrong time was entered.

Here are some similar problems discussed. Unluckily I couldn't join these threads and add comments (not enough points?). So, sorry for opening a new thread for something that may be already answered.

Comment: I can't tell you HOW to fix this, but the CAUSE is that the output will have 20 inputs with ID `arrivalTime`. The validator will put a `FacesMessage` in the `FacesContext` specific to the inputs with that id. So, it's not validating all 20 inputs, it's validating just one but each equal `id` renders one message. Check the output source code.